# windows msg error 1722 when sending message

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, cmd.exe, lan

Lately I learnt to send a message through LAN with the command `msg` by using:

`msg /server:EAAULA114-07 * message`.

But I can't send messages to some PCs because it outputs:

`Error 1772 getting session names` and on others `Error 5 getting session names.`

It also outputs `Error 1722 getting session names` when I try to send a message to the whole network by using:

`msg /server:* * message` or `msg /server:192.168.1.1 * message`.

I tried changing the registry value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer]
"AllowRemoteRCP"=dword:00000001
```

But it still doesn't work.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the exact commands you are using and the full error message.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you, edited the post. I hope it explains better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive error 1772, the messenger service required to run on the destination pc is not running and the message could not be delivered.

Error 1722 is received if you have no admin rights for that area.

Error 5 means that you need to be local administrator to perform that action.

This basically means, if you are not the network administrator, there is basically nothing you can do.

Network administrators can use group policies to disable this feature too, so they can disable it on the entire network.

Comment: This is very interesting and helpful. Thank you for your time and attemption

Comment: Before I worked in IT, but worked in an administration office, I used to toy around with `net send` myself. :) I had ocasionally a newer pc where the service was turned off by default which would break this. I even had a chat app that would be used to send these messages in secret with collegues. :) PS. msg replaced net send.

Comment: Hehe, I'm in class and I'm trying to comunicate with my mates and other classes :^)